# When will Math.SE support the `\begin{xymatrix}` environment?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

I have seen the following two questions on meta:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/xymatrix-commutative-diagrams

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram.

Apparently it seems that Math.SE does not support the `\begin{xymatrix}` environment. When will this feature come into place? I looked at this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131555/5783) on tensor products and the `\begin{matrix}` environment looks terribly inadequate. I know of Arturo's fix in the link above, but I think if say we wanted a diagram with diagonal arrows it would be very messy.

Also, if `\begin{xymatrix}` comes into Math.SE does that mean that chat will have it to? I have been talking to some people on chat recently and felt that I desperately needed to be able to draw commutative diagrams easily on chat.

Comment: I think you forgot to tag this (pony).

Comment: There is something called XyJax, but it doesn't look like a very active project, nor does it claims to be production quality.

Comment: This seems like something you should be asking the MathJax devs, instead of here in meta...

Comment: @Henning: What is pony?

Comment: @mixedmath: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3675/5363) and [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IwantaPony).

Comment: @t.b. There's a pony tag? Really? Does this mean that the writers of the 4 pony-tagged questions were unaware of its meaning?

Comment: @mixedmath: Yes, unfortunately. [No, it doesn't...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3674/5)

Comment: @Henning, really? We're *encouraging* the bad joke that is (pony)? Great, I'm going to start tagging all my meta questions (thoroughbred) from now on.

Comment: @HenningMakholm This is certainly not a request for a pony. Just today I was trying to type up an answer on tensor products. Then I realised that math.se supports no commutative diagrams and I was like sigh.....

Comment: Well, the fact that you _really_ want it is unlikely to  make it less ponysome to provide.

Comment: @Henning The [XyJax package](http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html) has undergone quite the expansion over the last few months. It is now compatible with the latest MathJax version as a plug-in. The bugs I've submitted so far were dealt with within a reasonable time span. So maybe it's a good thing to look at it again? (Sorry for grave-digging.)