# Fixing an AMScd diagram

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to fix this diagram and also extend it to the diagram below.
Can you help me out?

$\require{AMScd}$

$\begin{CD}
S^{n-1}@>\subseteq >> D^n \\
@VhVV  @VVV\\
S^{n-1}\\
@V\subseteq VV  @VVV\\
D^n @>>>\Sigma^n(h)
\end{CD}$

The 'double-down-arrow' on the right side of the diagram is supposed to be just one arrow, but I did not manage to fix this. I am not familiar with constructing those diagrams. I am thankful, when someone fixes it, or tells me how to fix it.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know solution using AMScd. (As far as I know, AMScd only has horizontal and vertical arrows.)

If you are familiar with xypic, you could use this syntax and include it as a picture. (You create it either locally on your computer or using some online tool, for example, the [presheaf website](http://presheaf.com/).) It is reasonable to include somewhere (maybe as a comment in your post) the source of the diagram, too.

For example, you can get this diagram: http://presheaf.com/?d=d3j4t1z705k6j154i2k5u2v4y113a4v36 http://presheaf.com/cache/d3j4t1z705k6j154i2k5u2v4y113a4v36.png

[image: commutative diagram]

```
S^{n-1} \ar[r]^{\subseteq} \ar[d]_h & D^n \ar[dd] \ar@/^/[rddd]^q & \\
S^{n-1} \ar[d] & \\
D^n \ar[r] \ar@/_/[rrd]_p & \Sigma^n(h) \ar@{-->}[rd] & \\
&& S^n
```

Another popular package to create commutative diagrams is tikzCD - I am pretty sure that somebody familiar with it can provide you source code to get your diagram. (And also for this package you can do it either online or locally.)

See also:

- [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324) - one of the answers mentions xypic and presheaf
- [Triangle commutative diagram does not work here at MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4072) and [Is it possible to use tikzcd code in MO posts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3792) on MathOverflow Meta
- Posts on the main site [with links to presheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*presheaf.com*%22)
- [Your professional $\LaTeX$ experiences that saves your time in typesetting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319980#319983) - an answer with a link to online tikzcd editor

Comment: Why dont they include these packages here? It seems overly complicated to use other sources. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Cornman: Because MathJax is not $\rm\LaTeX$, and compiling something on your personal computer in native machine code is far faster than running it through the many layers of interpretation and emulation when you run it in your browser, and ultimately many people use handheld devices to browse the site.

Comment: @Cornman I do not know much about web applications, but including xypic or tikzcd into MathJax seems to me rather difficult task. Of course, you can quite easily find some related past discussions, such as:[When will Math.SE support the `\begin{xymatrix}` environment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3984), [Using TikZ on math.stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9545) or [Can we support TikZ picture rendering?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26652)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Still seems odd, that MathJax does not have a reliable way to draw complex diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

$$\raise{34px}{\vert}\hspace{-5px}\raise{17px}{\vert}\hspace{-12.2px}\downarrow$$
`\raise{34px}{\vert}\hspace{-5px}\raise{17px}{\vert}\hspace{-12.2px}\downarrow` is a very crappy stand in.

$$\underset{\mid\raise{-12px}{\hspace{-3px}\backslash\underline{\phantom{444444444}}}}{}$$
`\underset{\mid\raise{-12px}{\hspace{-3px}\backslash\underline{\phantom{444444444}}}}{}`
There are ways to do the other arc as well, but as you can see, it's a bit of a pain. Also just random MathJaX but breaks on edit it seems.